# Unable to query new table from asp.net core web application using EF 1.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have developed a new asp.net Core web application using Visual Studio 2015. I am at the point where I am adding user customization options by adding additional tables to my local database. However I have been unable to add whatever EF needs to query a new table correctly. I get the following error when attempting to query the table..

Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this issue

There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been applied to the database
•00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema

Apply Migrations

In Visual Studio, you can use the Package Manager Console to apply pending migrations to the database:
PM> Update-Database 
Alternatively, you can apply pending migrations from a command prompt at your project directory:

> dotnet ef database update

My table is a simple table with a few varchar or nvarchar columns.  The model looks something like...

```
namespace MyNamespace.ColorSchemes
{
    public class ColorSchemesViewModel
    {
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string bc { get; set; }

}
```

Table looks something like this in SQL Server...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ColorSchemes](
    [Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [bc] [nchar](7) NOT NULL
)
```

I have added the table to the application context like such...

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ColorSchemesViewModel> Colors { get; set; }
```

I have also used as separate class similarly like..

```
    public DbSet<ColorSchemes> Colors { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

}

I have added the context to a controller like this...

```
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public MyController(IMemoryCache memoryCache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ChordMVCController>();
        _context = context;

    }
```

I have tried to query the table in my controller like this...

```
        var colorSchemes = (from c in _context.Colors
                            select c).ToList();
```

I have attempted to use the Package Manager to per instructions from the error...

```
PM> Update-Database
```

I always get this error...

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
```

This doesn't make sense since this table is already in the database and the EF definition. How do I get my table added properly to the EF migrations so I can query it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this myself...

I created a different context rather than trying to embed the dbset in the default ApplicationDbContext and also removed the onModelCreating method.

```
public class ColorSchemeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ColorSchemeDbContext(DbContextOptions<ColorSchemeDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ColorScheme> ColorSchemes { get; set; }
}
```

Replaced the ApplicationDBContext with the new context in my controller class...

```
    private readonly ColorSchemeDbContext _context;
    public MyController(IMemoryCache memoryCache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ColorSchemeDbContext context)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ChordMVCController>();
        _context = context;

    }
```

After that the query worked. I spent a lot of time attempting to use the EF migrations to create the tables from a class syntax. Nothing seemed to work. I was creating a new .NET CORE web application in VS 2015 with the template and using user authentication which creates the AspNetRoles tables in SqlLite once you do an update-database. It is very confusing how to add additional tables using a code first approach after that. A lot more documentation is needed regarding EF migrations with respect to managing projects over time. I see the benefits of having all of your database updates maintained from your VS project but it is not easy to understand.